# What are some use cases of changing the fixed frame in rviz?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example if you change the fixed frame to /odom, and visualize the LaserScan data, how does the visualization come out different ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392341/what-are-some-use-cases-of-changing-the-fixed-frame-in-rviz-?/) by [rigidlab](https://answers.ros.org/users/91119/rigidlab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may want to change the fixed frame so you can view something in another frame of reference. It can be useful when debugging information, transformations, or wanting a steady look. There are as many reasons to want to view data in a certain frame as there are frames to look at the data in.

For your `odom` example, you may want to do this so you could view data in a frame unaffected by global localization updates and is promised to be smooth and continuous for measuring drift in odometry using sensor measurements to determine ground truth. Or perhaps I'm interested in looking at a robot's sensor data while navigation isn't running, so visualizing it in the `base_link` frame will work regardless of the `map` or `odom` transformations are available.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rigidlab](https://answers.ros.org/users/91119/rigidlab/) on 2021-12-16**:
Thank you.